# Scalable web project architecture

Tags: performance, scalability

Where do you get info about 'how to build scalable, high perfomance web app'? I mean architecture, best practice ets. regardless of platform and language: .net, php, java ... 
Did you get your own 'epic fails' in your project and then refactor your system in a few nights or get info from internet?

Is there any communities where I could share my own expirience and get some response?

Yeah, I know that every project is individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to answer this question. Language and Platform takes a secondary place when thinking about scalability.

"*Scalability is actually a property of a system, not an individual layer of that system, infrastructure. Even with the best, sexiest, most automatic scaling layer, you can easily write code that just doesn't scale. - glyph*"

How ever, you can immerse into a very good collection of resources on this issue at

- http://www.royans.net/arch/library/

Comment: Thanks fo link. "Language and Platform takes a secondary place when thinking about scalability." I agree with it, but a few days ago i watched video about scaling php web-project (on highscalability.com) and there were very interesting things for me about dns and load balancing :)

Answer (score 3):

You can read the [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) blog. If you have questions about architechture and scalability, you can always use StackOverflow unless the question is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Just focusing on the web part of scalable web architecture, you might want to take a look at these [7 reasons why you should be using XMPP instead of AJAX](http://www.dynamicalsoftware.com/ajax/xmpp) especially if your web app needs to scale with lots of real-time social features.